# Delete relationship between two entities MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

Hi everyone,

I'm using MagicalRecord and I try to remove a relation established between two entities

Contact <<--->> Group

A contact can be related to several groups and a group can also be related to several contacts.

For instance, Ben is in Group 1, Alex is also in Group 1, I want to remove Ben from Group 1.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you just don't set his group to nil and save context.(if group entity is optional of course)?

Comment: Well, I only want to remove this contact from one group, if I set his groups to nil he'll not be related to any group anymore.
And yes, I can do that, and then repopulate his groups but it is a bit brutal I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use method from CoreDataGeneratedAccessors category of your NSManagedObject's subclass. If name of your relation's set is `groups`, the name of this generated method is `removeGroupsObject`.